# String pool in java, compile time vs run time string evaluations

Tags: java, string

I am study on getting my OCA exam and stuck on this java string pool concept.

Consider the follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "Hello";                // since s1 and s2 are the same literal at compile-time, therefore they will be string pooled
    String s2 = "Hello";

    String s3 = "Hello".trim();

    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("Hello");     // although they are the same string, == only checks for object equality
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("Hello");

    System.out.println(s1 == s2);       // true
    System.out.println(s1 == s3);       // true
    System.out.println(sb1 == sb2);     // false

}
```

`s1` and `s2` are identical in string AND also identical in object because since it is the same string literal, the JVM will string pool `s1` and `s2` at compile-time.

Now, `s3` is **computed** at run-time and therefore should return a new string. Therefore, `s1 == s3` should be false, but that is not the case. Why?

One theory I have is the `trim()` method checks to see if there are any white space to remove to begin with, if it doesn't, then simple return itself. That would explain why `s1 == s3`, but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: [The method's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) confirms your hypothesis : "If [...] the first and last characters of character sequence represented by this String object both have codes greater than '\u0020' (the space character), then a reference to this String object is returned. ".

Comment: Your fault lies specifically in the "therefore" part of your second-to-last paragraph: yes, `s3` is computed at runtime, but it happens to resolve to the same instance as `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: Ctrl+click on `trim()` will show you the code. I learnt a lot like that.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. If the trim() method doesn't change the value, then the original instance will be returned. If all the "Hello" was changed to " Hello", s3 would not be equal to s1 as trim() would remove the whitespace and return a new string instance.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct if you look at the source of the `trim()` method, you would see that after removing the whitespaces the `substring(start, end)` is invoked. Else if there were no whitespaces then the same instance `this` is returned.

```
public String trim() {
   int len = value.length;
   int st = 0;
   char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

   while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
       st++;
   }
   while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
       len--;
   }
   return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
 }
```

Here `st` is the start index after removing the whitespaces and `len` is the new length.

Now if there was any whitespace like before or after the string:

```
String s1 = "hello "; //<-- whietspace at the end
System.out.println(s1.trim() == "hello");
```

The output is `false` as the `substring()` was invoked by the `trim()` method. The substring returns a new String instance if the `beginIndex` and `endIndex` is not the same:

```
return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
                : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
```

So after removing the whitespaces if any, the `beginIndex` and `endIndex` would obviously change and a `new String()` instance will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source code for trim(). If there's no whitespace to remove, then it returns `this`. So it's the same reference you `trim`ed.

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```